# iterate through and obtain sum

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

I'm building a simple invoice app. I have an invoice model which has_many :items and :items belongs_to :invoice.

As far as the model schema goes, :invoices simply has a column for storing a title, and :items takes care of all the (pricing) amount and quantity details.

I have an invoices index, where a list of invoices is shown with their "total amount". The total amount for each invoice is determined through a "quantity_amount_sum" method I have set up in the item model which takes all of the items of the invoice and multiplies the quantity by the amount to determine the total of all items on the invoice.

model: item.rb

```
def quantity_amount_sum
   return self.quantity * self.amount
end
```

index.html.erb

```
<% @invoices.each do |invoice| %>
$<%= invoice.item_amount.sum.floor %>
<% end %>
```

model invoice.rb

```
  def item_amount
  @@item_amount = self.items.map(&:quantity_amount_sum)
  end
```

The problem is in trying to then sum up a "grand total" for the index page (ex: two invoices, each with a sum of items. Invoice #1 totals $100, invoice #2 totals $200. I then want a "total" of invoices, which should be $300). I've tried iterating through each of invoices using "each do" for the total, but I have only been able to retrieve the sum for the last invoice, never the two combined.

```
$<%= @invoices.total_val.each.sum %>
```

model invoice.rb

```
 def self.total_val
     @@item_amount
  end
```

This would produce the sum of only the last invoice (or $200), whereas the total should be $300.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want sum of total of both invoices then you can change this line:

```
<% @invoices.each do |invoice| %>
$<%= invoice.item_amount.sum.floor %>
<% end %>
```

to this:

```
$<%= @invoices.map(&:item_amount).flatten.sum %>
```

However, I see that you're approaching items to calculate invoice's total amount. I'd encourage you to add a new column called: `total` to `invoices` table instead. Later, you can create a callback in your `Invoice` model:

```
before_save :update_total

def update_total
  self.total = self.items.map{|i| i.quantity_amount_sum }.sum
end
```

Which will be easy to access and iterate in future when your data grows. Also, please make sure that you have another callback in `Item` class which update the related `Invoice`'s total in case if an item is being edited.

Then your view can be changed to:

```
$<%= @invoices.map(&:total).sum %>
```

Also, you don't have to write `return` here:

```
def quantity_amount_sum
  self.quantity * self.amount
end
```

Ruby return the last expression by default.